# Is there any function that can keep the data change every selection is been selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, ajaxform

I am doing a select with multiple attributes and this is my code. I need an opinion on how to avoid data not been to see after sent it to ajax.

So my code is after the change is made. The data should change too if the class mapping has been detected. But the data does not change. It affects on 1st change only.

This form.blade.php

```
<!-- Content -->
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4>{{msg('lbl_update_mapping')}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ $route }}" method="post">
            {{ method_field('put') }}
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <table id="marketingsetting-table" width="100%" class="table table-striped b-t b-b">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Funnel Stages</th>
                        <th>Value</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach($marketing_status as $value_ms)
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:60%"> {{$value_ms->name}} </td>
                        @if($value_ms->code == 'L')
                        <td> {!! Form::multiDropdown($value_ms->name.'[]', $marketing_mapping, ' ', ['id'=> $value_ms->code, 'class'=>"select2-form mapping"]) !!} </td>
                        @elseif($value_ms->code != 'L')
                        <td> {!! Form::multiDropdown($value_ms->name.'[]', [], ' ', ['id'=> $value_ms->code, 'class'=>"select2-form mapping"]) !!} </td>
                        @endif
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="col-lg-2 pull-right">
                {!! Form::buttonSave('','') !!}
                {!! Form::buttonCancel('',route('marketing.marketing_mapping.index')) !!}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- /content -->
@push('scripts')
<script>
// var table = $('#marketingsetting-table').DataTable({
//     {!! Config::get('datatable.setting') !!}
//     ajax: '{!! $datatableroute !!}',
//     columns: [
//         { sTitle: '{{msg("lbl_marketing_status")}}', mData: 'name', width:'80%'},
//         { sTitle: '{{msg("lbl_value")}}', mData:'marketing_mapping', orderable:false },
//     ],
// });

</script>
@endpush
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('.mapping').on('change', function(){
        var mapping = $(this).val();
        var id_lead = $('#L').val();
        console.log(id_lead);
        getData(mapping);
    });

    function getData(d_mapping){

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '{!! route("marketing_mapping.mappingAjax")!!}',
            data:{mapping:d_mapping},
            success:function(data){
                var select_data = [];
                var count = 0;

                $.each(data, function(i, object){
                    count++;
                });

                if(count != 1){
                    select_data.push({id:'', text:''});
                }

                $.each(data, function(i, object){
                    select_data.push({id:i, text:object});
                });

                $('.mapping').select2({ data: select_data });
                updateSelect2('.mapping');
            },
            error:function(data){

            }
        });
    }

    function updateSelect2(element)
    {
        $(element).select2({
            placeholder:'Please Select',
            allowClear:true
        });
    }

});
</script>
```

MappingController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Setting\Marketing;

use App\Helpers\Forms as Form;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\MarketingMapping;
use App\Models\MarketingStatus;
use App\Repositories\Marketing\MappingRepository;
use App\Repositories\Marketing\MarketingStatusRepository;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables;

class MappingController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(MappingRepository $mapping, MarketingStatusRepository $marketingstatus)
    {
        // Authorization
        $this->middleware('authorize')->only(['index', 'edit']);
        $this->marketingstatus = $marketingstatus;
        $this->mapping         = $mapping;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $mappingsetting = $this->mapping->findBy('is_active', 1);
        $data           = [
            'breadcrumb'     => array(msg('lbl_setting', [], true) => route('setting'), msg('lbl_marketing'), msg('lbl_mapping')),
            'content'        => 'setting.marketing.marketing_mapping.list',
            // 'submenu'    => 'setting.marketing.navigation',
            'title'          => msg('lbl_mapping'),
            'settingtitle'   => msg('lbl_marketing'),
            'mappingsetting' => $mappingsetting,
            'datatableroute' => route('marketing.marketing_mapping.getData'),
        ];

        return view('layouts.setting_template')->with($data);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $mappingsetting = $this->mapping->findBy('is_active', 1);
        // $marketingstatus = $this->marketingstatus->findby('is_active', 1);
        $marketingmapping = $this->mapping->getSelection();
        $marketingstatus  = MarketingStatus::where('is_active', '1')->get();

        $data = [
            'breadcrumb'        => array(msg('lbl_setting', [], true) => route('setting'), msg('lbl_marketing'), msg('lbl_mapping')),
            // 'submenu' => 'setting.marketing.',
            'content'           => 'setting.marketing.marketing_mapping.form',
            'title'             => msg('lbl_mapping'),
            'settingtitle'      => msg('lbl_marketing'),
            'toggle'            => 'mapping',
            'mappingsetting'    => $mappingsetting,
            'route'             => route('marketing.marketing_mapping.update', 1),
            'datatableroute'    => route('marketing_mapping.getDataID', $id),
            'type'              => $id,
            'marketing_status'  => $marketingstatus,
            'marketing_mapping' => $marketingmapping,
        ];

        return view('layouts.setting_template')->with($data);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        dd($request->all());
        $data = $request->except('_token', 'marketingsetting-table_length', '_method');

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

            $marketing_status = json_encode($value);

            $userid = Auth::id();
            $date   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            $general = MarketingStatus::where('name', $key)->update([
                'marketing_mapping_id' => $marketing_status,
                'updated_by'           => $userid,
                'updated_at'           => $date]);
        }

        \Session::flash('alert-success', 'Record Successfully Updated');
        return redirect()->route('marketing.marketing_mapping.index');
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        // $mappingsetting = $this->mapping->findBy('is_active', 1);
        // $marketingstatus = $this->marketingstatus->findby('is_active', 1);
        $marketingstatus   = MarketingStatus::where('is_active', 1)->get();
        $marketing_mapping = MarketingMapping::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->all();

        return Datatables::make($marketingstatus)
            ->addColumn('name', function ($marketingstatus) {
                return $marketingstatus->name . '<br /><span class="text-muted">' . $marketingstatus->description . '</span>';
            })
            ->addColumn('marketing_mapping', function ($marketingstatus) use ($marketing_mapping) {
                $json_data    = $marketingstatus->marketing_mapping_id;
                $json_data    = array_flip($json_data);
                $mapping_data = array_intersect_key($marketing_mapping, $json_data);
                $mapping_name = implode(',', $mapping_data);
                return $mapping_name;

            })
            ->rawColumns(['name'])
            ->toJson();
    }

    public function getDataID($id)
    {
        $marketingstatus = $this->marketingstatus->findby('is_active', 1);

        $mappingsetting = $this->mapping->findBy('is_active', 1);

        return Datatables::make($marketingstatus)
            ->addColumn('name', function ($mappingstatus) {
                return $mappingstatus->name . '<br /><span class="text-muted">' . $mappingstatus->description . '</span>';
            })
            ->addColumn('marketing_mapping', function ($marketingstatus) {
                $marketingmapping = $this->mapping->getSelection();
                return Form::multiDropdown($marketingstatus->name . '[]', $marketingmapping, ' ', ['class' => 'mapping select2-form', 'id' => $marketingstatus->code]);
            })
            ->rawColumns(['name', 'marketing_mapping'])
            ->toJson();
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function getMappingAjax(Request $request)
    {
        $mapping_id = $request->get('mapping');

        $mapping_data = MarketingMapping::whereNotIn('id', $mapping_id)->pluck('name', 'id')->all();

        return $mapping_data;
    }

}
```

This is result update:
[image]

This is page view before changes on Lead row:
[image]

[image]

[image]

The changes happen after data selected in lead row:
[image]

The reason I'm doing this is to avoid a repeating selected with the same data. Is there any way to simplify the process?

Comment: show result of dd($request->all()); in function update

Comment: @GzaiKun i have add the dd();